# How can I display elements from an array of strings only if their length is greater then zero in this app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am working on an SPA with Vue 3, TypeScript and The Movie Database (TMDB).

The app displays list of *movie cards*.

In the **MoviesList** component (`src\components\MoviesList.vue`), I have:

```
<template>
    <div class="row list">
       <div v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.id" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
        <MovieCard :movie="movie" :genres="genres" />
    </div> 
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import env from '../env';
    import MovieCard from './MovieCard.vue';

    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'MoviesList',
        components: {MovieCard},
        props: {
            listType: String
        },

    data() {
      return {
        pageTitle: "Now Playing",
        movies: [],
        genres: [],
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      this.getMovies();
      this.getGenres();
    },

     methods: {
      getMovies() {
        axios.get(`${env.api_url}/movie/${this.$props.listType}?api_key=${env.api_key}`).then(response => {
          this.movies = response.data.results;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      },

      getGenres() {
        axios.get(`${env.api_url}/genre/movie/list?api_key=${env.api_key}`).then(response => {
          this.genres = response.data.genres;
          console.log(this.genres);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

In the **MovieCard** component (`src\components\MovieCard.vue`), I have:

```
<template>
    <div class="movie card">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img :src="`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${movie.backdrop_path}`" :alt="movie.title" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>

        <div class="card-content">
            <h2 class="card-title">{{ movie.title }}</h2>
            <p class="card-desc">{{ movie.overview }}</p>
            <span :title="`Score: ${movie.vote_average}`" class="score d-flex">{{ movie.vote_average }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer">
            <p class="m-0 release">Release date: {{ dateTime(movie.release_date) }}</p>
            <p class="m-0 pt-1">
                <a class="genre" v-for="genre in movie.genre_ids" :key="genre.id">
                    {{ getGenreName(genre) }}
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
  import moment from 'moment';

  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'MovieCard',

    props: {
        movie: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        },

        genres: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    
  methods: {
    dateTime(value: any) {
            return moment(value).format('MMMM DD, YYYY');
        },

        getGenreName(gid: number) {
            if (this.genres[gid]) {
                if (this.genres[gid].name.length) {
                    return this.genres[gid].name;
                }
            }
        }
    },
  });
</script>
```

#### The problem

I use the below condition to make sure no empty genre conrainers are displayed:

```
if (this.genres[gid].name.length) {
    return this.genres[gid].name;
}
```

For a reason I have been unable to understand, this fails, as seen below.

[image]

#### Questions

1. What is my mistake?
2. What is the most reliable way to get the desired result?

Comment: You mention that "this fails" - can you tell us in what way it fails? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Does it display in some way you are not expecting? What are you expecting? What do you get?

Comment: @AndyPreston There is no error, it just does not work as expected. See the screenshot I have added.

Comment: You could add `console.log(gid, this.genres);` at the start of `getGenreName()` to verify that this parameter and property are as you expect them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues is that you use `:key="genre.id"` as key. Yet `v-for="genre in movie.genre_ids"` tells us that `genre` is probably an ID (number). Therefore `genre.id` will probably result in `undefined`, meaning that each iteration has the same `key`. This might result in rendering issues.

---

Next up, the empty tag(s) also tell us that there is no return value for `{{ getGenreName(genre) }}`.

You've included a lot of if-statements in an attempt to resolve this issue, but if a genre ID is not present in `this.genres` the function returns `undefined`. The same happens if the genre name is empty. Instead of returning an empty string, you'll return `undefined`, which results in practically the same result.

To solve this let's ask the following question first. If a movie genre ID is not present in `this.genres`. Did you load all the genres? The API might paginate the response, meaning that you have to do multiple calls to get a complete list of genres.

If you are sure you've loaded all the genres, and there are indeed genre IDs that don't match a genre, or genres with an empty name. We could use a computed property to solve the issue.

```js
computed: {
  movieGenres() {
    return this.movie.genre_ids
      .filter(genre_id => genre_id in this.genres)
      .map(genre_id => this.genres[genre_id])
      .filter(genre => genre.name.length > 0);
  }
}
```

Now instead of looping through `movie.genre_ids` you can loop through `movieGenres` instead.

```html
<a class="genre" v-for="genre in movieGenres" :key="genre.id">
  {{ genre.name }}
</a>
```

Note that `genre` in the above is the actual genre object and no longer just an ID. This is due to the `.map(genre_id => this.genres[genre_id])` we do in the computed property.

---

Instead of using a computed property there is also the option to improve the data delivery. Instead of passing "invalid" data as property you could sort the data out whenever you get a response from the API.

Comment: It is unclear to me what I should do and in what component(s). I get a lot of errors if I try to follow you. Note that I use TypeScript.

Comment: The `computed` properties should be placed in the `MovieCard` component (similar to `props` and `methods`). The provided template is a replacement for `<a class="genre" v-for="genre in movie.genre_ids" :key="genre.id">{{ getGenreName(genre) }}</a>` in the same component. Regarding the errors, what errors do you get?

Comment: It works, except there are only 20 genres and a lot more _genre ids_ on the cards. Which makes some cards show _no genre_.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I've addressed that in my answer if you read it completely. See: *"If a movie genre ID is not present in `this.genres`. Did you load all the genres?"*

Comment: Ho do I load all the genres, if the Themoviedb API _returns only 20_, to my knowledge, at least.

Comment: Try logging `response.data` in `getGenres()`. Does it contain any pagination information? The [API documentation](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/) also seems to have 2 different endpoints to get the genres. One for movie genres `GET /genre/movie/list` and one for TV show genres `GET /genre/tv/list`. Does your "movies" list contain any TV shows by accident? Does this second endpoint contain the genres that are currently missing?